# How to pause audio player when video player starts playing?

Tags: android, audio, video, android-video-player

I am developing an audio player, it can play the audio files in background. My problem is that I need to pause the audio player when video recorder or video player is starts.

Are there any methods to handle this task? For example I have `PhoneStateListener` to handle the calls. When I received a call or wnat to make a call we can pause the player by using call state. I want the same scenario for the video recorder or video player aswell. When video/recording starts I need to pause my audio player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to detect if there are other apps request audio focus and pause your audio player.
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener should help. Here is some sample code

```
am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT){
                // Pause playback
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                // Resume playback 
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                abandonAudioFocus();
            }
        }
    };
```

I did not try this code myself, let me know if it helps.

Comment: what is the type of afChangeListener?

Comment: what is this abandonAudioFocus();
method? what I ahve to handle in this method?

Comment: am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);  will abandon the audio focus.

Comment: This article provide clearer explanation for the audio focus concept, got sample code as well.
http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Handling-Audio-Sound-from-Overlapping-with-VOIP-call